# Modalities of conversion from NCDF to raster with R

Tags: r, coordinates, average, raster

I am using environmental data layers from Copernicus and as they are available in NCDF format I'm converting them in raster to be able to manipuplate them with QGIS. I use the following script :

```
## Output: a GeoTIFF file
file.tiff <- 'currents_2021.tiff'

## Import netCDF
currents_2021 <- raster(file.nc)

## Save to disk as GeoTIFF
writeRaster(currents_2021, filename = file.tiff, format = 'GTiff', overwrite = T)

## For multiple files, could use a for loop
## Input directory
dir.nc <- '~/ENSAT/Mobilité/Stage 2A/Archipelagos/Seabirds project/Environmental variables/Currents/2021'
files.nc <- list.files(dir.nc, full.names = T, recursive = T)

## Output directory
dir.output <- '~/ENSAT/Mobilité/Stage 2A/Archipelagos/Seabirds project/Environmental variables/SST/requested_files'
```

It works but the problem is that I have datas that are over 1 year (and collected every day), so for each latitude and longitude, several values of the variable considered are associated - theorically 365, one per day. I don't know how the raster function deals with that and which value it takes for each coordinate. I wouldlike to have an average of the year, so in each case of the raster an average of all the value associated, but I don't know if this script does it automatically. Does anyone knows that ?
Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 0):

`?raster` illustrates that `raster::raster()` has a `band` argument: *Integer. The layer to use in a multi-layer file.*

Since you are reading netCDF files (with 365 layers in your case), it seems like `raster::raster()` is only able to read one layer at once. If you don't provide any `band` argument, `band = 1` is chosen per default.

```r
library(raster)
library(ncdf4)

raster::raster("chirps-v2.0.2006.days_p25.nc")
#> class      : RasterLayer 
#> band       : 1  (of  365  bands)
#> dimensions : 400, 1440, 576000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#> resolution : 0.25, 0.25  (x, y)
#> extent     : -180, 180, -50, 50  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#> source     : chirps-v2.0.2006.days_p25.nc 
#> names      : Climate.Hazards.group.InfraRed.Precipitation.with.Stations 
#> z-value    : 2006-01-01 
#> zvar       : precip

raster::raster("chirps-v2.0.2006.days_p25.nc", band = 40)
#> class      : RasterLayer 
#> band       : 40  (of  365  bands)
#> dimensions : 400, 1440, 576000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#> resolution : 0.25, 0.25  (x, y)
#> extent     : -180, 180, -50, 50  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#> source     : chirps-v2.0.2006.days_p25.nc 
#> names      : Climate.Hazards.group.InfraRed.Precipitation.with.Stations 
#> z-value    : 2006-02-09 
#> zvar       : precip
```

The object returned is a single-band `RasterLayer`. You can import a multi-layered file (such as data coming from a netCDF container) at once making use of `raster::stack()` instead:

```r
nc_data <- raster::stack("chirps-v2.0.2006.days_p25.nc")
nc_data
#> class      : RasterStack 
#> dimensions : 400, 1440, 576000, 365  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
#> resolution : 0.25, 0.25  (x, y)
#> extent     : -180, 180, -50, 50  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#> names      : X2006.01.01, X2006.01.02, X2006.01.03, X2006.01.04, X2006.01.05, X2006.01.06, X2006.01.07, X2006.01.08, X2006.01.09, X2006.01.10, X2006.01.11, X2006.01.12, X2006.01.13, X2006.01.14, X2006.01.15, ...
```

As you can see, the result consists of 365 layers this time. You can now subset the `RasterStack` object to query individual layers if you like, ...

```r
nc_data[[40]]
#> class      : RasterLayer 
#> band       : 40  (of  365  bands)
#> dimensions : 400, 1440, 576000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#> resolution : 0.25, 0.25  (x, y)
#> extent     : -180, 180, -50, 50  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#> source     : chirps-v2.0.2006.days_p25.nc 
#> names      : X2006.02.09 
#> zvar       : precip
```

... and you can now simply make use of `raster::mean()` on your stack to calculate average values over all 365 layers, corresponding to the yearly average you requested, and write the resulting single-band raster to disk using `raster::writeRaster()`:

```r
nc_mean <- raster::mean(nc_data)
nc_mean
#> class      : RasterLayer 
#> dimensions : 400, 1440, 576000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#> resolution : 0.25, 0.25  (x, y)
#> extent     : -180, 180, -50, 50  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#> source     : memory
#> names      : layer 
#> values     : 0, 71.93983  (min, max)
```

If you want to find out how to read and write netCDF files using `terra`, see my [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73092643/11709296). Just make sure to change the file extension in `terra::writeRaster()` from `asc` to `tif`.